# How to display a tooltip on the navigation controls in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am building a mapbox-gl-js application for very inexperienced users and looking to provide as much guidance as possible.  The standard icon buttons for zoom in / out/ gelocate etc are great but as an extra bit of help I would like to display a tooltip on mouseover with a textual description of what the button does "Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Zoom to current location" etc.

I have checked the API docs and looked at the source code in github but cannot see an option to provide this customisation.  If anyone else has successfully done this or have some suggestions on how this could be achieved without forking mapbox I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prettiest solution will be to use the `options.locale` API
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/

A patch to apply to the default localization table for UI strings such as control tooltips. The locale object maps namespaced UI string IDs to translated strings in the target language; see src/ui/default_locale.js for an example with all supported string IDs. The object may specify all UI strings (thereby adding support for a new translation) or only a subset of strings (thereby patching the default translation table).

in the default_locale.js one can find all the default tooltips

```
const defaultLocale = {
    'AttributionControl.ToggleAttribution': 'Toggle attribution',
    'AttributionControl.MapFeedback': 'Map feedback',
    'FullscreenControl.Enter': 'Enter fullscreen',
    'FullscreenControl.Exit': 'Exit fullscreen',
    'GeolocateControl.FindMyLocation': 'Find my location',
    'GeolocateControl.LocationNotAvailable': 'Location not available',
    'LogoControl.Title': 'Mapbox logo',
    'NavigationControl.ResetBearing': 'Reset bearing to north',
    'NavigationControl.ZoomIn': 'Zoom in',
    'NavigationControl.ZoomOut': 'Zoom out',
    'ScaleControl.Feet': 'ft',
    'ScaleControl.Meters': 'm',
    'ScaleControl.Kilometers': 'km',
    'ScaleControl.Miles': 'mi',
    'ScaleControl.NauticalMiles': 'nm'

};
```

Also, some cntrl elements such as the full-screen button have an internal state and based on this state, UI have a different tooltip content, that means that you cannot overwrite the tooltip value of these elements